# Add border and header row background color to Angular material datatable

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I need to add table border and `header row` background color to my Angular datatable. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!-- Date Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.date}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Download Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Download">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Download </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.download}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

The above code is generating the output like below.

[image]

But here I need the complete table border and also `the first row background color` to this `Angular material datatable` using CSS which should looks like below.

[image]

So like the above image I need to add the border and header row background color. As I have no experience on `CSS` can anybody please help to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with styling material:

- we cannot overwrite them inside component without using ::ng-deep which is deprecated
- there is a lot of template generated by material inside every html tag

But it's possible, altho it's a lot of hassle.

If you want to change background color of header row add:

```
.mat-header-row::ng-deep {
  background-color: black;
}
```

To your css.

If you want to add border to table add:

```
.mat-table::ng-deep {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You just need to adjust colors to your pleasure :)

Second solution without using depracated ::ng-deep will be adding styles to your global style.css rather than to component, then you need to add just:

```
.mat-header-row
{
  background-color: black;
}
.mat-table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Its seems ok . I added like `.mat-table {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  

  .mat-header-row{
    background: #005173;
}` but the header font color is not changing and also not visible.

Comment: add `.mat-header-cell { color: red; }`

Comment: I am using like `.mat-header-row{
    background: #005173;
}

.mat-header-cell { color: white; } ` but the header font color not reflecting.

Comment: maybe some other style is overwriting it? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvxmhe?file=src/app/table-basic-example.css on stackblitz it's working fine